# Is it a bad practise to pass the http servlet response in my service layer?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

In my login method of my authenticationService, I need to create a cookie and set the session ID in the cookie.

Is it bad practise to pass the request object to my service layer inside of a controllers action?

```
public void login(String email, String password) {

   User user = someService.validate(email, password);

   if(user != null) {
      // create session
      // set cookie ????
   }

}
```

My controller action will call the login method above, confused where I should be creating and setting the session id for my cookie.

It makes sense to me to have this in the service layer, but then my login method is then tightly bound to a web application.

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes (to "bad practice"), no (to "doing this right").

The service layer should be completely decoupled from anything having to do with the web. The web layer alone should be responsible for managing web-layer artifacts, including cookies.

This way the service can be used even when cookies don't exist, like a desktop or CLI app. It also allows testing the service without considering the web-layer at all, which makes sense--the service doesn't care *how* authentication happens, or what happens after--only that using a username and password works.

Comment: so once the user is authenticated, the session has to be written to the db, shouldn't the service layer do that? or it is the same as the cookie?  THEN where should this be, in the controller?

Comment: @Blankman Not sure why a session or session ID *has* to be written to the DB, but your app may require that. I don't think most do, but it all depends. In any case, the service should should get a session ID from the controller, and still remain decoupled from the web layer.

Comment: +1 supposedly "multi-tiered" architecture that is coupled to the web straight through every layer is a huge peeve!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Try to turn network messages into domain objects as soon as possible, and don't take any actions until you've decided that the whole message is well-formed and authorized.

Your code will be more maintainable and secure if you can isolate the code that deals with messy untrusted inputs from the code that implements business rules, and enacts changes based on domain objects, from the code that formats a response to the outside world.

If you can separate your service into:

1. A simple layer that turns an HTTP request into domain objects,
2. A (possibly complex) operation on domain objects that produces a result,
3. A simple layer that turns a result into an HTTP response,

then you can focus unit-testing on 2 without worrying about creating and populating stub request and response objects.